# Apache won't start in CentOS 7 due to missing SSLCertificateFile

Tags: apache, centos

Apache does not start after installing the web server. (CentOS 7)

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-03-28 12:18:22 MSK; 16ms ago
Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
Process: 30144 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 30144 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Status: "Reading configuration..."

Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain httpd[30144]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 103 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain httpd[30144]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt' does not exist or is empty
Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Answer (score -7, accepted):

The error message is very clear:

> SSLCertificateFile: file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` does not exist or is empty

Remove this invalid configuration or add missing/fix existing certificate file. Either way to have to fix the configuration before Apache can start.

Obtaining an SSL certificate is out of the scope for StackOverflow. There're plenty of resources on the web, you can try on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) too…

When you're done, simply `sudo systemctl start httpd` to start Apache.

Comment: This answer is rightfully downvoted because the issue here is that when `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` exists, the mentioned localhost certificate file should also exist, as both are created as a result of the installation of mod_ssl. So if you just do the normal thing you've always done and you suddenly run into this error, it is very confusing. Per another answer here on SO that I currently cannot recover, the solution is usually to restart Apache once, at which point the certificate file is created after all.

Answer (score 1):

You could try by creating a fake certificate.

In centos there is a handy script which might help

```
$ cd /etc/pki/tls/certs
$ sudo ./make-dummy-cert localhost.crt
```

This script produces a self-signed certificate and the certificate's private key.

Therefore SSLCertificateKeyFile in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf could be commented out

```
SLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
# SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

Otherwise service won't start

Answer (score 1):

> Mar 28 12:18:22 box-40395.localdomain httpd[30144]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt' does not exist or is empty

The error message said the SSLCertificateFile is missing. You can use the following command to generate those files to work around this issue.

```bash
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key -x509 -days 365 -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running `systemctl reload httpd` after installing `mod_ssl` (I was previously serving HTTP only).

Solution: run `systemctl restart httpd.service`; the files `/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` and `/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key` will be created and httpd will start without errors.